# How do we prove that $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2} }}$ as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Definition:

$$f(x) \sim g(x) \iff \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1 \enspace \text{as} \enspace x \to \infty . $$

Let:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \sim  g(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}. $$

Why those two functions are similar? If two functions are similar either both converge or both diverge.

I get, using L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^{-1/2}2x}. $$

Comment: is it using l'hospitals in the limit?

Comment: Note that (for the functions you specified) we have $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$.

Comment: $\approx$ is wrong for this notion, $\sim$ is used.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews true  I but dont know how to write that one in latex

Comment: `\sim` @SirMrpirateroberts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for l'Hôpital here:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} & = \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + 1}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{x^{2} + 1}} = 1.
\end{align*}

Comment: can you explain what you did?

Comment: Sure. I have rearranged the argument of the square root as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + 1} = \frac{(x^{2} + 1) - 1}{x^{2} + 1} = \frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{2} + 1} - \frac{1}{x^{2} + 1} = 1 - \frac{1}{x^{2} + 1}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts you are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using L'Hopital's rule,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} = 1$$